# write size threshold for select call return

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

When the `select` Linux system call returns when provided with valid file/socket `writefds` , what are the write payload sizes for which a subsequent call to write will not block? E.g. is it 1B / 1kB / 1MB or some other threshold? And where is this threshold set?

```
int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds,
           fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);
```

Comment: I don't think there's any way to know in general. Some device types may have an ioctl that can be used to determine the available buffer space.

Comment: I don't think there's a threshold. The usual strategy is to make the fd non-blocking when you use `select/poll`. So if there isn't enough space, you'll get `EWOULDBLOCK`.

Comment: I guess the question is what is "enough" space?

Comment: It's at least the size that you try to send.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, how does select know that?

Comment: It doesn't. I meant you call `send()/write()` to try to send the data, and there isn't room it will return `EWOULDBLOCK`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what are the write payload sizes for which a subsequent call to write will not block?

In simple words, `select` guarantees that the writable file is able to accommodate at least **1 byte** without blocking.

---

Generally, after a successful `select` call a single non-blocking `write` call will succeed with **any** size of payload.

Note, however, that successful write could return just 1 with meaning that only 1 byte has been actually written. For write the rest bytes a `write` call should be repeated, but that second `write` is allowed to block (or return EWOULDBLOCK if called on non-blocking file descriptor).